# Contract First vs Contract last in current generation

Tags: spring, rest, cxf, contract-first

The question might sound absurd. Every where when I see the difference between Contract First and Contract Last, I see the word WSDL.

How does it fit in the current world of annotation and JSON Objects? Does it map like

Contract-First --> Use definitive Java class as Request Object
Contract-last -> Use generic hashmap as Request Object

Comment: Maybe for JSON Objects I would talk about _WADL_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Contract First look for the synonym API First. I use Swagger/ Open API Specification for that approach. As you tagged the question with CXF the Swagger2Feature might be interesting for you: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/swagger2feature.html

What you named Contract Last is Code First that means you write your Java classes first, annotate them and the Contract (WSDL, WADL, Swagger) will be generated afterwards.